# Which `IntPtr` flavors are candidates for a `SafeHandle`

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, roslyn-code-analysis, safehandle

I am getting a CA2006 ("`Review usage of ... (a 'IntPtr' instance) to determine whether it should be replaced with a SafeHandle or CriticalHandle`") for an `IntPtr` returned from `ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor` which I know is a security descriptor that can be freed with a `FreeLocal`.  I am using it only briefly and probably not leaking the memory involved.  No kernel handle is associated as far as I can tell.

There are lots of `SafeHandle` subclasses and none of them appear to be calling `FreeLocal` at the end of life of the wrapped object.  However, I can't find any definitive information concerning which `IntPtr` instances (say, returned by the Win32 API) are usefully managed by a `SafeHandle` and which ones are not.

Should I just suppress the CA warning?

More importantly, how to determine the same for the next `IntPtr` usage I will run into?

(A table that would map `SafeHandle` subclasses to the functions that will eventually free the handle would be great.)

Comment: It is not wrong, just serious over-kill.  You consider it when you write a finalizer to release the resource.

Comment: @HansPassant - This helps, but finalizers themselves are gray zone beasts.  They are about tying the lifetime of a resource to another random resource (small chunk of managed heap).  They are at best a second level of defence, never accomplishing anything reliably on their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is "is there already a `SafeHandle` subclass that calls `LocalFree` to free its handle", then yes, there is -- it's [`SafeLocalAllocHandle`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/Microsoft/Win32/SafeHandles/SafeLocalAllocHandle.cs). The class is `internal`, so it's not available to the general public, but the code is obvious if you wanted to recreate it. If your question is "should I use such a class", well, that's a bit of a judgment call. [`CA2006`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182294) and the [`SafeHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle) documentation explain the design rationale: `SafeHandle` avoids issues with handle recycling in multithreaded scenarios and has special support for P/Invokes to ensure handles aren't accidentally freed before unmanaged code is done with them.

When is an `IntPtr` a handle that could be wrapped by `SafeHandle`? You won't be able to tell from the `IntPtr`, you have to know what function is returning the `IntPtr`. It will document whether or not you're dealing with a handle and if so, how you should close the handle when you're done with it (very often, but by no means always, `CloseHandle`). If you only have a P/Invoke signature, then technically, you have nothing. In particular, it will not be possible to determine what function should be called to free the handle, if it is a handle. An `IntPtr` can also be used to marshal `PVOID` or `SIZE_T` or `P<some_struct>` (even though `out` or `ref` parameters are more natural for that) or any other type that's supposed to be pointer-sized.

Any handle-as-`IntPtr` that escapes beyond a single function (especially one stored in a field) is a really good candidate for a `SafeHandle` wrapper, as is any use of multiple `IntPtr`s at the same time (to prevent accidentally mixing up incompatible handles). For a simple one-off that involves no multithreading and doesn't let the handle escape beyond its scope, a `try .. finally` block is probably enough.  If you want, everything can be wrapped in a `SafeHandle` for consistency's sake (or to explicitly document what object type you're dealing with), but that doesn't necessarily lead to better results. Handle recycling is a serious issue, but not a concern here since the handle is to local memory, and reliability isn't an issue because any problem serious enough to bypass a `finally` block is also serious enough to make a small memory leak a non-issue.

Your particular scenario (parsing SDDL into a security descriptor) is already implemented in the framework in the form of [`RawSecurityDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/y707fyek), which you should consider using in favor of reinventing the wheel (and/or implementing your own `SecurityDescriptor` subclass if it's not already covered by the existing classes in [`System.Security.AccessControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.accesscontrol). For what it's worth, `RawSecurityDescriptor` also P/Invokes to `ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW` and doesn't bother with a `SafeHandle`. Framework code should not necessarily be treated as a good example of what to do (plenty of code violates the official guidelines), but it's something.